# Find the constant in Weibull distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $f(x) = kx^{\beta-1}e^{-\alpha x^\beta}$, $x>0$, how do I find the constant $k$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? I know that the entire integral needs to evaluate to $1$. Also How do I find the expected value in terms of alpha and beta?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the substitution $t = x^\beta$.